# Como usar o metodo de encriptação openssl_encrypt?

Tags: php

Faz uma semana que pesquiso em tudo que é site mas não consigo entender, estou muito curioso a respeito do uso dessa função mas não encontro nada que explique de forma simples, alguém pode me ajudar por favor ?

Comment: Porque a descrição da pergunta tem só esse pequeno trecho de texto? Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters aparentemente ele [editou](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/145385/1), não sei por qual razão.

Comment: @Inkeliz você explicou muito bem, preferi tirar do meu texto algumas coisas que achei desnecessárias e confusas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Esta resposta foi totalmente modificada, afim de corrigir erros nos exemplos e evitar a má utilização deste recurso. Além disso foi acrescentado o uso de recursos do PHP 7.1 e do PHP 7.2, antes não disponíveis.

---

O `openss_encrypt`, assim como o `openssl_public_encrypt`, são métodos de criptografia que são reversíveis. Eles possibilitam ao detentor da chave privada ver o texto original. Isso pode parecer óbvio, porém existem métodos criptográficos onde o proposito é justamente impedir a recuperação do texto original.

---

### Uma chave para ambos os lados:

O `openssl_encrypt` permite que utilize vários tipos de cifras simétricas, por exemplo o DES, 3DES, AES, CAMELLIA. Cifras simétricas requerem que ambos os envolvidos (quem envia e recebe) tenham o conhecimento da mesma chave.

Você é capaz de ver todas as cifras "suportadas" utilizando:

```
var_dump( openssl_get_cipher_methods() );
```

Em geral a maior parte das pessoas usam o que a NIST define, ou seja usa o AES (e no passado usavam DES e depois 3DES). Na verdade ao usar AES você está utilizando o Rijndael com parâmetros definidos pela NIST, o Rijndael foi vencedor da mesma competição.

O CAMELLIA é um padrão europeu (definido pela CRYPTREC e NESSIE), equivalente ao AES, ele tem menor utilização e consequentemente também menor número de ataques conhecidos até o momento.

Enfim, confie em quem você quiser e use a cifra que quiser e que cumpra com o objetivo desejado.

### Não-autenticada:

Este método impede que uma pessoa sem a posse da chave e apenas olhando o `$TextoCifrado` consiga saber o que foi escrito. Porém, você NÃO impede que essa pessoa faça alterações no texto. Um exemplo seria a pessoa alterar o IV, ela pode fazer isso e isso iria "virar" alguns bits do primeiro bloco, que ainda poderia tornar o texto compreensível ao humano, as vezes mudando o sentido do texto.

#### AES-CBC:

```
// Não dê CTRL+C e CTRL+V neste código, ELE TEM PROBLEMAS DEPENDENDO DO SEU USO!
// Não ignore isto, leia acima!

$TextoClaro = 'Um texto muito bacana e muito legal';
$Cifra =  'AES-256-CBC';

// $Chave =  random_bytes(32);
$IV = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($Cifra)); 

$TextoCifrado = openssl_encrypt($TextoClaro, $Cifra, $Chave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV);

echo $Resultado = base64_encode($IV.$TextoCifrado);
```

**Explicações:**

O `$TextoClaro` e `$Cifra` acredito que sejam auto-explicativos, por si só já dá para saber o que se referem.

Já o `$Chave`, `$IV` e `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` podem parecer estranhos.

- `$Chave`: Primeiro é preciso distinguir o que é um chave e uma senha. Isto não é um senha, senhas são fracas, senhas são um conjunto de caracteres selecionados por um humano. Nunca utilize senhas como chaves. As chaves devem ser fortes, neste caso 256 bits, de uma fonte segura e de um gerado que é seguro (o `random_bytes` foi incluído no PHP 7 e ele é um CSPRNG). Ela deve ser secreta e mantida em segredo, a criptografia só vai funcionar enquanto ninguém souber esta chave.
- `$IV`: O `IV` é um vetor de inicialização, ele é utilizado para realizar a primeira operação contra o primeiro bloco da cifra, na maior parte das cifras. Isso garante que mesmo que duas mensagens iguais gerem resultados diferentes, desde que o IV seja diferente. Justamente por essa propriedade o IV deve ser único e nunca deve repetir com a mesma chave, mas não há necessidade de ser secreto e nem mesmo ser aleatório. O IV pode ser passado junto com o `$TextoCifrado`, como é feito acima.
- `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`: Ele é usado para que o resultado seja em bytes (ao invés de codificado em base64), isso é feito porque nós juntamos o `$IV` ao `$TextoCifrado`, portanto não faz sentido usar um base64 dentro de outro. Este mesmo parâmetro também poderia receber o `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`, se isto fosse usado o `$TextoClaro` deveria ter um comprimento múltiplo do tamanho do bloco (de 16, neste caso), uma vez que o *padding* não seria feito automaticamente.

O `$Resultado` é exatamente o `BASE64([IV]+[Texto Cifrado])`, supondo que `+` seja concatenação.

#### Descriptografar:

Para "descriptografar" nós usamos o `openssl_decrypt`:

```
$Resultado = base64_decode($Resultado);

$TextoCifrado = mb_substr($Resultado, openssl_cipher_iv_length($Cifra), null, '8bit');
$Cifra =  'AES-256-CBC';

//$Chave = pack('H*', 'be3494ff4904fd83bf78e3cec0d38ddbf48d0a6a666be05420667a5a7d2c4e0d');
$IV = mb_substr($Resultado, 0, openssl_cipher_iv_length($Cifra), '8bit');

echo $TextoClaro = openssl_decrypt($TextoCifrado, $Cifra, $Chave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV);
```

O `$Resultado` presupõe ser o `$Resultado` da operação anterior. Além disso a `$Chave` deve ser a mesma da operação anterior, não use esta chave usada no exemplo! O `$TextoCifrado` e o `$IV` serão extraído usando o `mb_substr` uma vez que ambos estavam concatenados num mesmo base64.

---

### Autenticada:

Uma forma de impedir a "maleabilidade" é garantido integridade, óbvio. Isto é utilizar AES-GCM (disponível no PHP 7.1), usar um HMAC (disponível no PHP 5.6) ou utilizar o ChaCha20-Poly1305 (disponível no PHP 7.2 ou via PECL), irei mencionar todos aqui.

**ChaCha20-Poly1305 (requer PHP 7.2 ou PECL):**

Se você prefere por não usar o AES, assim como eu... Você tem a opção de utilizar o `ChaCha20-Poly1305` usando o LibSodium, que está disponível no PHP 7.2. Ele garantirá que o texto não foi modificado, para utiliza-lo é muito simples:

```
$TextoClaro = 'Um texto muito bacana e muito legal';
$TextoPublico = ''; // Opcional, ele pode ser um ID de usuário, por exemplo, que NÃO SERÁ criptografado!

//$Chave =  random_bytes(32);
$IV = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES);

$TextoCifrado = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_encrypt($TextoClaro, $TextoPublico, $IV, $Chave);

echo $Resultado = base64_encode($IV . $TextoCifrado);
```

Depois para recuperar o texto:

```
$Resultado = base64_decode($Resultado);

$TextoCifrado = mb_substr($Resultado, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, null, '8bit');
$IV = mb_substr($Resultado, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES, '8bit');

$TextoPublico = '';
//$Chave = pack('H*', 'be3494ff4904fd83bf78e3cec0d38ddbf48d0a6a666be05420667a5a7d2c4e0d');

echo $TextoClaro = sodium_crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_decrypt($TextoCifrado, $TextoPublico, $IV, $Chave);
```

*Note, caso utilize o `$TextoPublico` você terá que fazer algumas adaptações.*

**AES-GCM (requer PHP 7.1):**

O padrão de todos, você pode usar o `AES-GCM` no lugar do `AES-CBC`, nele entretanto você deverá informar um novo parâmetro, o `$Tag`. Ao contrário do LibSodium, exemplo acima, ele não adiciona a TAG automaticamente ao final da string, então no final ficará:

```
$Cifra = 'AES-256-GCM';
//...

$TextoCifrado = openssl_encrypt($TextoCifrado, $Cifra, $Chave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV, $TAG);

echo $Resultado = $IV.$TAG.$TextoCifrado;
```

A `$Tag` irá garantir que o texto não foi alterado, ele usa o GMAC. Você também pode incluir um outro parâmetro, após o `$Tag` para incluir alguma informação não criptografada, por exemplo o `id` de usuário:

```
$TextoPublicoAdicional = 123;

openssl_encrypt($TextoCifrado, $Cifra, $Chave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV, $TAG, $TextoPublicoAdicional);
```

O `$ID_DO_USUARIO` ficará em texto claro (não será criptografado), porém será coberto pelo GMAC, ou seja se ele for modificado será notado. Não há mistério para descriptografar, basta utilizar o `$IV` e `$TAG` contido no `$Resultado` e usar o `openssl_decrypt`.

**AES-CBC + HMAC (requer PHP 5.6):**

Se você não conseguir utilizar nada disso, você pode usar o HMAC e comparar para vê se o texto foi ou não alterado, para isso portanto você precisa utilizar outra chave e fazer um HMAC do resultado:

```
$TextoClaro = 'Um texto muito bacana e muito legal';
$Cifra =  'AES-256-CBC';

//$ChaveHMAC = random_bytes(32);
//$Chave = random_bytes(32);

$IV = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($Cifra)); 

$TextoCifrado = openssl_encrypt($TextoClaro, $Cifra, $Chave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV);

$HMAC = hash_hmac('sha384', $IV . $TextoCifrado, $ChaveHMAC, true);

$Resultado = base64_encode($HMAC . $IV . $TextoCifrado);
```

Isso irá conter os 384 bits (48 bytes) do `$Resultado` o HMAC do texto, neste caso esto usando `sha384`, você pode usar outros algoritmos de hash. Isso irá garantir que qualquer alteração no texto irá fazer a hash do HMAC ser inválido.

Então para conferir o resultado, para descriptografar:

```
$Resultado = base64_decode($Resultado);

$TextoCifrado = mb_substr($Resultado, 48 + openssl_cipher_iv_length($Cifra), null, '8bit');
$Cifra =  'AES-256-CBC';

//$Chave = pack('H*', 'be3494ff4904fd83bf78e3cec0d38ddbf48d0a6a666be05420667a5a7d2c4e0d');
//$ChaveHMAC = pack('H*', '4f55622d36ca62310f3b85ba933d84e65cd3241e4cabe08802fb611da713ef9b');

$IV = mb_substr($Resultado, 48, openssl_cipher_iv_length($Cifra), '8bit');

$HMAC = mb_substr($Resultado, 0, 48, '8bit');

if(!hash_equals(hash_hmac('sha384', $IV . $TextoCifrado, $ChaveHMAC, true), $HMAC)){
  echo "O texto foi alterado";
  exit();
}

echo $TextoClaro = openssl_decrypt($TextoCifrado, $Cifra, $Chave, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV);
```

Observe que estou colocando o IV dentro do HMAC, isso é extremamente importante.

---

> **NOTA:**

Em nenhum os casos você está protegido contra *replay-attack*, um terceiro pode armazenar os textos cifrados (bem como a tag e os iv) e num momento futuro enviar essas informações novamente. Uma maneira de conter isso é incluir um número sequencial ($i++) dentro mensagem, isso também identifica a perda de mensagens. Existe uma outra opção que é incluir uma data-hora, entretanto o problema da data-hora é que um agente pode atacar os servidores NTP usados para obter o horário correto, por exemplo, nesta situação automaticamente invalidaria as mensagens legitimas.

Comment: A variável `$Chave` está comentada no seu primeiro código. Por que? Não entendi muito bem. Essa chave é única? Eu gero ela uma vez e guardo pra usar posteriormente nas próximas transações? Porquê quando dou um `echo` nela, aparece caracteres estranhos pra mim.

Comment: Porque a `$Chave` deve ser a "sua chave", dependendo do objetivo, ela deve ser uniformemente aleatória. Essa chave é única? Ela deve ser única, qualquer pessoa que souber da chave poderá decifrar a mensagem. Eu gero ela uma vez e guardo? Depende, você quer ter acesso a este conteúdo no futuro ou isso será enviado uma única vez? Se quer resgatar a mensagem num ponto futuro armazene a chave.  Porquê quando dou um `echo` aparece caracteres estranhos? Porque o UTF-8/ASCII não tem todos os bytes pintáveis, exemplo: `0x00` é nulo e o `0xFF` não existe no ASCII, por isso mostra uma caractere "errado"

Answer (score 2):

### Duas chaves diferentes:

Se você quer utilizar criptografia assimétrica você busca o uso do `openssl_public_encrypt`, nele você poderá utilizar uma chave pública. Você pode gerar uma chave privada usando `openssl_pkey_new`, assim poderá divulgar sua chave publica e permitir que terceiros lhe envie mensagens usando a chave pública, onde somente você, com a chave privada saberá o conteúdo dela.

O problema do `openssl_public_encrypt` é que ele é bem precário, por padrão utiliza um padding quebrado (usando `OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING` ao invés do `PENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`) e mesmo o `PENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` ele utiliza SHA1]. Além de não suportar ECC, ele é restrito ao uso do RSA, ao menos até agora.

Portanto não irei mencionar o uso do OpenSSL e seu RSA. Todos os exemplos são usando o LibSodium, suportado nativamente no PHP 7.2.

### Autenticada:

Você pode utilizar o `crypto_box` e o `crypto_box_open` para criptografar uma mensagem e ainda manter a integridade, além de conseguir identificar quem enviou a mensagem.

Neste caso você precisa de dois pares de chaves (um par de chaves para Alice, um par de chaves para Bob), cada um terá conhecimento de três chaves, da seguinte maneira:

```
$AliceKP = sodium_crypto_box_keypair();
```

Isso irá um par de chaves (Keypair, KP), para Alice. O BOB terá que fazer o mesmo:

```
$BobKP = sodium_crypto_box_keypair();
```

Logo, fazemos:

```
$AliceKP = sodium_crypto_box_keypair();

// Chave pública de Alice (que será compartilhada com Bob):
$AlicePK = sodium_crypto_box_publickey($AliceKP); // 8c133d34045ac249dac1f572f3e452f1644166cb56b9f23d75f132dae56d2477

// Chave privada de Alice:
$AliceSK = sodium_crypto_box_secretkey($AliceKP); // ae70f388f19b9d7739f342df31abe722a7791f9bd1831e9a4db703112aad2696
```

O Bob precisa nos enviar a chave pública dele, para isso:

```
$BobKP = sodium_crypto_box_keypair();

// Chave pública de Bob (que será compartilhada com Alice):
$BobPK = sodium_crypto_box_publickey($BobKP); // d8b91792ce11783fa4b32bfcb3f636c3785d0589e35a2b3b30aec5019c690d61

// Chave privada de Bob:
$BobPK = sodium_crypto_box_secretkey($BobKP); // 3b505365150b8f42014416ecffa546ef4e6196d69d8c4a1782458ebb3117776e
```

No final o Bob passará para Alice o `$BobPK` e Alice compartilhará o `$AlicePK` para Bob. Agora podemos criptografar o texto:

```
$AliceKP = sodium_crypto_box_keypair();

// Chave privada de Alice:
$AliceSK = pack('H*', 'ae70f388f19b9d7739f342df31abe722a7791f9bd1831e9a4db703112aad2696');

// Chave pública de Bob:
$BobPK = pack('H*', 'd8b91792ce11783fa4b32bfcb3f636c3785d0589e35a2b3b30aec5019c690d61');

// Cria par de chaves entre Alice e Bob:
$AliceParaBobKP = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(
    $AliceSK,
    $BobPK
);

// Gera um número único (equivalente ao IV):
$Nonce = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES);

// Criptografa o texto:
$TextoCifrado = sodium_crypto_box(
    'Meu texto muito bacana, muito legal',
    $Nonce,
    $AliceParaBobKP
);

echo $Resultado = base64_encode($Nonce . $TextoCifrado); // nCfABXic/JghqSaXHuUvWYdZ1LrDVkOCQLleSw51LtRtOpy1D+XH8XMZMD6djFGJUC/aCsxO5j7ogd90WTmadI6sWklmpu/bRi5m
```

Agora Alice pode compartilhar com Bob o seu `$Resultado`. O Bob poderá ler o texto de alice usando:

```
$Resultado = base64_decode('nCfABXic/JghqSaXHuUvWYdZ1LrDVkOCQLleSw51LtRtOpy1D+XH8XMZMD6djFGJUC/aCsxO5j7ogd90WTmadI6sWklmpu/bRi5m');

$TextoCifrado = mb_substr($Resultado, SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES, null, '8bit');
$Nonce = mb_substr($Resultado, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES, '8bit');

// Chave privada de Bob:
$BobSK = pack('H*', '3b505365150b8f42014416ecffa546ef4e6196d69d8c4a1782458ebb3117776e');

// Chave pública de Alice:
$AlicePK = pack('H*', '8c133d34045ac249dac1f572f3e452f1644166cb56b9f23d75f132dae56d2477');

// Cria par de chaves entre Bob e Alice (a ordem mudou!):
$AliceParaBobKP = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(
    $BobSK,
    $AlicePK
);

$TexoClaro = sodium_crypto_box_open(
    $TextoCifrado,
    $Nonce,
    $AliceParaBobKP
);

echo $Resultado = ($TexoClaro ?: 'Erro ocorrreu');
```

### Anonima:

Se você não quer ter que trocar as chaves públicas ou o remetente não possui um par de chaves, então você pode enviar mensagens anonimas usando o `crypto_box_seal`:

```
$BobPK = pack('H*', 'd8b91792ce11783fa4b32bfcb3f636c3785d0589e35a2b3b30aec5019c690d61');

$TextoCifrado = sodium_crypto_box_seal(
    'Um texto bacana, mas anonimo',
    $BobPK
);

echo $Resultado = base64_encode($TextoCifrado); // bgSXKQmj4nc0JYtYYk1rsp6P/OuCqv1ThdRJCokoQBkMY8N57C0gCiVQLT/dkOu0mFVgNc+c1OXJa6nZcFoP6YzGHH6LZRzRLrTPTg==
```

Então Charlie pode mandar uma mensagem para Bob sem que o Bob tenha conhecimento de sua chave pública, ou seja o Bob não vai saber quem enviou a mensagem. O Bob por sua vez pode abrir a mensagem utilizando:

```
$BobPK = pack('H*', 'd8b91792ce11783fa4b32bfcb3f636c3785d0589e35a2b3b30aec5019c690d61');
$BobSK = pack('H*', '3b505365150b8f42014416ecffa546ef4e6196d69d8c4a1782458ebb3117776e');

// Cria par de chaves entre Bob e Bob (sim, ele e ele mesmo):
$BobKP = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(
    $BobSK,
    $BobPK
);

$TextoClaro = sodium_crypto_box_seal_open(
    base64_decode($Resultado),
    $BobKP
);

echo $TextoClaro;
```